# Java Object Reference Redundancy

Tags: java, hibernate, zk

I am currently working on Order module. I have a Order model class.. and while implementing it with Hibernate .. i am using the sorting order like asc, desc... Now the problem i am facing is ... the Order class of Hibernate API is referencing the Order Model class of mine.. Isn't there anyway to fix except for renaming my Order Model class...

This is Hibernate sample code..

```
Criteria criteria = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Order.class);
Order order = (Order) criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("documentNumber", documentId))
        .add(Restrictions.ge("creationDate", date))
        .addOrder(Order.desc("id")).setFirstResult(0).setMaxResults(1).uniqueResult();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sure, use fully qualified name (e.g com.xxx.yyy.Order)